# Source NAT happening on requests between nodes of the same cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to reproduce the same experiment as explained at [here](https://v1-17.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/#source-ip-for-services-with-type-clusterip).
Basically the experiment is about making an HTTP request from a pod inside a cluster to another pod inside the same cluster, but I'm not able to get the same result.
I have a pod with the following IP: 10.1.97.85/24, in the same cluster of another
pod which has an application that sends an HTTP response with the IP address of the client that sent the request. As said [here](https://v1-17.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/#source-ip-for-services-with-type-clusterip), the following is true:

> Packets sent to ClusterIP from within the cluster are never sourced NAT’d if you’re running kube-proxy in iptables mode

I have performed the test cited above, but when I perform the request from the pod with IP address 10.1.97.85/24 I receive an HTTP response saying that the request was sent by a pod with IP 10.1.97.1, I would like to know what is happening.

I have performed the experiments above with microk8s and kubernetes on version 1.17.9, and both pods are on the same nodes since I have just one node.

I have created my deployment with the command:

```
microk8s.kubectl create deployment source-ip-app --image=k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4
```

The above command created the pod with the application that will echo the client_address in the HTTP response.

I have exposed the above deployment with the command:

```
microk8s.kubectl expose deployment source-ip-app --name=clusterip --port=80 --target-port=8080
```

I have started another pod with the command:

```
microk8s.kubectl run busybox -it --image=busybox --restart=Never --rm
```

And inside the pod created above i have done the command:

```
ip addr
```

With the above command i got the ip address: 10.1.97.85 but when i performed a wget to the service i have received back the ip address: 10.1.97.85

Comment: You appear to have forgotten to include the actual code you used to test, since the conditions of the test matter a great deal

Comment: If there is anything else i can add to make it more clear, please let me know.

Comment: Did you run `wget -qO - clusterip` and received: `client_address=10.1.97.85` ?

Comment: No, i run `n wget -qO - clusterip` and received `client_address=10.1.97.1`

Comment: Can you try running `modprobe br_netfilter` like suggested [here](https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/1139#issuecomment-627375759) ?

Comment: I'm sorry. Before you commented here i removed microk8s from my laptop. When i saw your comment i installed it again and it worked just fine. Now with everything working the result of running `modprobe br_netfilter` is empty. Thank you.